# What does EVE:Tyrannis offer for the casual, solo gamer?

Tags: eve-online

Used to play EVE a few years back, got to around 3mil SP I think, so not really that good to be honest

Just looked up the latest patch, looks quite good.

What does the game offer for a solo casual gamer? Thinking of dipping back in, but don't have a guild/corp so would that mean planetary stuff is off limits?

Answer (score 2):

It depends what area of the game interests you most.

You can certainly become a trader, miner or manufacturer on your own, however I think the game comes into it's own when you're part of a larger entity where your contribution really matters.

In terms of planetary stuff, have a look here: http://wiki.eveuniversity.org/w/index.php?title=Planetary_Commodities I'm up to tier 2, and could get to tier 3 on my own, but the trick is to find the right commodity to invest your time in. (as always).

Planetary manufacturing is almost solely single player at the moment as you cannot set up automatic manufacturing between different players at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

As with most things in EVE, being in nullsec yields more profits. The planets in nullsec and WH space seem to produce more products than HighSec.

Truth be told, the Planetary Interaction isn't going to make you rich overnight, infact, all we using it for currently is to product POS fuels. So that saves us a little bit of ISK. The main game hasn't changed that much at all with PI stuff.

I would suggest you join a corp like EVE University that will teach you the basics of "corp life". Most nullsec corps happily accept EVE university guys. Once you in nullsec, the game of EVE evolves. I currently run a trade route from HighSec to nullSec and I am making a killing ;)

The game really opens up in NullSec so try it out.

Answer (score 0):

Exploring is a decent way to earn profits and is often a solo or small-group activity in empire space.  If you jam a scanner onto an assault frigate or BC you can earn a fair bit of isk in mid-highsec space (0.5-0.6) by nabbing radar sites.